# Get current view for Android in cross-platform (Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, cross-platform, custom-renderer

How can I get current view/layout in Android Xamarin by `CustomMapRenderer` class? I want to add view in current layout at specific position.

**In iOS I am doing it by following lines:**

```
UIView XView;

XView.Frame = new CGRect(50,50,40,40);

Window.AddSubview(XView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Which View, specifically, are you after?  The Xamarin Forms Map itself?  Its container?  The underlying native Android Control?

If you're after the native control, you have a reference to it in the `Control` Property of your renderer.

If you're after the Xamarin Forms wrapper for the native piece (a `Map` in this case), then you want to use the `Element` property of your renderer.

Both have a `Parent` property and the `Element` has a `ParentView` property.

Comment: I am talking about main container view.

And I have used parent property to get current view but it returns null.